# Storefront Theme - CSS to shortcode on FrontPage

Tags: wordpress, shortcode, storefront

I tried to find an answer to my problem on many forums. Unfortunatelly I found nothing (or I could not understand the solution if it was any) So..

On my website front page (Storefront Theme) https://tricourilemele.ro/  I have 2 shortcodes:

`[product_categories number="6" columns="3" ids="56,57,397,390,581,901,4518" orderby="ID" ]`

and:

`[top_rated_products ="6" columns="3" ids="5909,5810,5585,4465,5840,5825" products orderby="ID" , order=”DESC”]`

Is it possible to have different CSSfor every shortcode?
If the question is too stupid I apologize..

Thanks & Kind regards,
Marius

Comment: Hi.  Your question lacks some details, but in short, the answer is yes you can.  You will have to inspect the elements and get the css classes in use.

Answer (score 0):

Depending where you are calling these shortcodes, if you are just placing them on the page using the editor, you can simply wrap the shortcode inside a div with your custom class:

```
<div class="first-custom-class">
[product_categories number="6" columns="3" ids="56,57,397,390,581,901,4518" orderby="ID" ] 
</div>
```

and

```
<div class="second-custom-class">
[top_rated_products ="6" columns="3" ids="5909,5810,5585,4465,5840,5825" products orderby="ID" , order=”DESC”]
</div>
```

is this what you were looking for?

Comment: I think what you said  is what i was looking for..  These div class should be defined somewhere?

Comment: I mean..  <div class="first-custom-class">  should be specified where?